# How to pattern match in Lua

Tags: lua

So let's say I have this in Lua:

```
myvara = "Box red"
myvarb = "Box red 36"
```

How do I form an expression to see if both variables are the same if the number changes every time?  i.e. I just want to check if both variables are red boxes but the number is not important.

I want to use pattern matching but I don't know how to do so efficiently and in an expression.  I don't want to use string.find, it has to be pattern matching.

What I need to be able to do is:

```
if myvara == myvarb (ignoring box number) then...
```

... with pattern matching (not string.find or anything like that).

Oh, and there might be a different number of words sometimes and the number might be in a different place.  That's why I need to use pattern matching.

Thank you.

Comment: "*with pattern matching (not string.find or anything like that).*" `string.find` [uses pattern matching](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.find).

Comment: There's a lot of different methods on that page.  Which should I be using?  Would it be string.gsub or string.match or another?  I want to be able to do it in one statement (so no for loops or anything).

Comment: Replace all numbers with digit 0 before comparing: `if myvara:gsub("%d+", "0") == myvarb:gsub("%d+", "0") then`

Comment: I updated my question slightly because I think I worded it wrong.  What if I want to check if 'red box' is equal to 'red box x' where x is any number?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all spaces and numbers from both strings before comparing them:

```
if (myvara:gsub("[%d ]","") == myvarb:gsub("[%d ]","")) then
  ....
```

Comment: I think I worded this all wrong.  Let me try again.  Let's say I have a string 'Red car 3'.  How would I output that to a new variable without the number 3 using pattern matching?  So I want the new variable to be 'Red car'.  And what about if it was 'Red 3 car' - again, how would I output that to a new variable using pattern matching?  The new variable should be 'Red car' again.  Is it possible without gsub?  Is it not possible to use gmatch or something and just have it omit the number?

Comment: If you only remove the number, then you end up with "Red car " (with trailing space) and "Red  car" (two spaces between words). Is that what you want? Or would you also need to remove one of the spaces preceding the number? What if the number is at the start of the string? I think you need to better describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: I guess I need to remove the space too.  So 'Red car 3' becomes 'Red car' and 'Red 3 car' becomes 'Red car'.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid `gsub`? Is it not available to you? It's much easier to remove the number than to extract everything else. Also, how about `Red Car3` (without space)? Remove the number as well?

Comment: Performance is key as there will be many expressions probably in a loop.  Is gsub acceptable to use where performance is key?  The number always need to be removed and the space trimmed.

Comment: You'll have to run the tests to see which approach is better, but it sounds like a case of premature optimization. I'd implement it with `gsub` first and then check if it creates any performance issues.

Comment: It may be that the best way to do it is string.match.  So I would say myvara = 'Red car 3' and string.match(myvara, 'Red car').  The string.match will return true because 'Red car' is part of 'Red car 3' regardless of spaces so this works.